# keeping positionning after selecting an item from comboboc

Tags: php, html

I have a form with 2 combobox: statutbox and categorybox, the statutbox is on the top of my page, but categorybox is in the middle.my problem is when i select an item from the categorybox which is in the middle , the page is refreshed and returns to the top.
so how to how to keep the same positioning.
here is my code:

```
   <form id = "formbox" name="form" method = "POST" action="parproj.php">    
<select id="statutbox" name="statut" onChange= "this.form.submit()" style= "width:300px;padding:2px;-webkit-border-radius:4px;-moz-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0;cursor:pointer;">

                <?php
                $reponse2 = $bdd->query('select name from issue_statuses order by name asc;');
                while ($donnees2 = $reponse2->fetch())
                {
                    $selected2 = (isset($_POST['statut']) and $_POST['statut'] == $donnees2["name"])?'selected="selected"':'';
                    echo '<option value="'.$donnees2['name'].'" '.$selected2.'>'.$donnees2['name'].'</option>'; 


                }

                $reponse2->closeCursor(); // Termine le traitement de la requête

                ?> 
              </select>

               </form>

<select id="categorybox" form="formbox" name="category" onChange= "this.form.submit()" style= "width:300px;padding:2px;-webkit-border-radius:4px;-moz-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0;cursor:pointer;">

                <?php
                while ($donnees3 = $reponsecat->fetch())
                {
                    $selectedcat = (isset($_POST['category']) and $_POST['category'] == $donnees3["category"])?'selected="selected"':'';
                    echo '<option value="'.$donnees3['category'].'" '.$selectedcat.'>'.$donnees3['category'].'</option>'; 
                }

                $reponsecat->closeCursor(); // Termine le traitement de la requête
               ?>
               </select>
```

Comment: your second `select` is out of the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions. Check the example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Scroll to an element</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #category {margin-top:500px}
    #article {margin-top:250px}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
<select name="status" id="status" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>    
</select><br />
<select name="category" id="category" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="button" />
</form>
<div id="article">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["status"]) && $_POST["status"] != 0){

        // 1st solution 
        header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "#category");

        // or

        // 2nd solution
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#category").offset().top}, "slow");</script>';
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Don't forget to comment the solution you won't use. `this.form.submit()` is optional, you may submit the form by a regular `submit` button.

Comment: it works for the two combobox, but i want that works only when i select an item from categorybox

Comment: @Salma I wrote an entire example for you so I hope you'll find it helpful. Give it a try :)

Comment: thank you so much, i tried the both of them , i've always been taken to the top of the page, i don't want to use the submit button :(

Comment: @Salma So, since this is not quite clear, did you solve your issue or not?

Comment: not yet, i tried your solution, but it has no effect, i can't see where is the problem :(

Comment: @Salma If you save the example above as a .php file it will work just fine - I tested it before pasted here. Otherwise, paste your code within your question, drop me a note here and I'll check it in the meantime.

Comment: I tested your example alone an it works, but im my case i test category , i'm not interested in testing status, i want when i click on category that i still in the same positionning

Comment: @Salma Well, change this `if(isset($_POST["status"]) && $_POST["status"] != 0){` to this `if(isset($_POST["category"]) && $_POST["category"] != 0){`

Comment: I found the error, in fact the problem come from this part : $_POST["category"] != 0) I change it by string and it works

Comment: @Salma By the way, that's not an error; that's the right way dealing with select list. Your default option on a select list should be `value = 0` and not `value = ''`. However, this `$_POST["status"] != 0` could be written also like this `$_POST["status"] != FALSE` and you (if you want) may use `0` or an empty string

Comment: @Salma Could you please tell me why you're not up-voting and accepting my answer since it helped you to solve the issue :)